# Evaluate the integral $(1/(1+x^2)) (\arctan x)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

I got $\arctan x(1/(1+x^2))^2$.

Because wouldn't the antiderivative of $1/1+x^2$ be $\arctan x$ and then $(\arctan x)^2$ just be $(1/(1+x^2))^2$ ?

Comment: When in doubt, differentiate your answer to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\arctan}{arctan}$
You seem to have the right ideas. The key observation here is indeed that derivative of $\arctan(x)$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

$$\int \frac{(\arctan x)^2}{1 + x^2} \: dx$$

Let $u = \arctan x$, then $du = \frac{dx}{1 + x^2}$.

Thus, $$\int u^2 \: du = \frac{u^3}{3} + C = \frac{(\arctan x)^3}{3} + C$$